# React js - dynamically create SVG

Tags: reactjs, svg

Whats to best approach to generate SVG element with multiple embedded svg elements in it and return as a react element?
I'm looking for something like following:

```
let s1 = <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="10" stroke="green" strokeWidth="4" fill="blue" />;

let s2 = <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" strokeWidth="4" fill="blue" />;
let tl = s1 + s2; // Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Element' and 'Element'.

return <svg>{tl}</svg>;
```

Comment: Does this `<svg>{s1}{s2}</svg>` work ?

Comment: yes, but I don't know number of svg elemnts from the begining. I'm thinking of using map method right now...

Comment: `map` will absolutely work. Something like `<svg>{svgArray.map(x => x)}</svg>`.

Comment: `map` is unnecessary. You can render `svgArray` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React can render arrays. Just change it in your code: `let tl = [s1, s2]`.